# Sencha Touch 2 default route

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, url-routing

I'm building a sencha touch 2 application, using routes. If I understand directly, this requires specifying routes in your controller, and leaving your app.launch function empty (or at least, not load a view / call a controller there).

One of my controllers specifies the "" route, which gets loaded when the url hash-part is empty (`http://localhost/`):

```
Ext.define('SOP.controller.PartyController', {
   extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        routes: {
           "": "showChooseParty"
```

so far so good....

However in this case, if the hash-part contains some junk (e.g. `http://localhost/#tralala`, when there is no tralala route specified in any controller), the app just hangs on the load screen: no action gets called, and the launch function is empty. What I would like is a route that gets loaded when the hash-part matches no known route (the hash-part junk may be a route in a previous version of the app, or facebook trying to make me happy supplying the accesstoken in the hash in a redirect).

I have a workaround working, in the launch function:

```
launch: function () {
    if (!this.getRouter().recognize(window.location.hash.substr(1))) {
        window.location.hash = "";
    }
},
```

however I don't like the code pointing directly to the hash, its working is dependent on launch() being called before the route is matched for the first time, and the this.getRouter() object is ["private" and not supposed to be used](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Router).

So my question, what is the "right" way to provide a default route? Or am I totally missing the point of using routes?

Answer (score 2):

After checking for a hash value in your launch function, you can do the following...

```
this.getApplication().getHistory().add(Ext.create('Ext.app.Action', {
        url : 'home'
    }));
```

Now you can use 'home' as your default route instead of an empty hash.

Comment: this works perfect, but in sencha 2.3.1 Ext.app.Action is marked as private. (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Action)
So what is the correct way to set an item in the application history?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, and I'm interested to hear what else you may have found, but I just implemented the following: Since Sencha Touch 2 routes are short-circuiting - that is, once a matching route is found, the Ext stops looking - you can add an `Error` controller to the end of your `controllers` list and add a route that matches anything:

In my app.js I have:

```
...
controllers: ['Whatever', 'AnotherOne', 'Error'],
...
```

I define whatever `routes` I need to in the first two controllers, then in `app/controller/Error.js` I have this:

```
...
config: {
  routes: {
    ':foobar': {
      action: 'showNotFound',
      conditions: {
        ':foobar': ".+"
      }
    }
  }
}
...
showNotFound: function(hash) {
  // do whatever you need to
}
```

So, anyone going to domain.com#whatever/456 would get the Whatever controller which may show a view of item #456, but if Ext gets all the way down to the `:foobar` route of the `Error` controller then they will hit my "404" page.

**NOTE: Your `:foobar` (404, Not Found, etc) route MUST BE LAST. That means the last controller in the list, and the last route in the config. Otherwise it will get hit before anything after it.**